# Linear independence of gradient vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find all feasible points that are regular for a function with constraints:

$h_1(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 2x_1x_2+x_3^2=0$

$h_2(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=4$

The definition says that if a point $x^*$ satisfies the contraints $h_i(x^*)=0, i = 1,...,m$ and if the gradient vectors $∇h_i(x^*), i=1,...,m$ are linearly independent then the point $x^*$ is a regular point.

So the gradient vectors I get in this case are

$∇h_1(x)=[2x_2,2x_1,2x_3]^T$

$∇h_2(x)=[2x_1,2x_2,2x_3]^T$

After messing around a bit, I found 6 points that satisfy the constraints.

Those points are $(-1,1,\sqrt{2}),(1,-1,\sqrt{2}),(0,2,0),(2,0,0),(0-2,0)$ and $(-2,0,0)$

I didn't bother to check all the points because surely there are more that satisfy the constraints. Instead I tried looking at the general case.

If $a(2x_2,2x_1,2x_3)+b(2x_1,2x_2,2x_3)=0$ is true such that $a,b$ are not $0$ then they are not linearly independent. But this is where I'm stuck. I can't tell for which $x$-s the vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Find the rank of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{2x_2 &2x_1 & 2x_3\\
          2x_1 &2x_2 & 2x_3}.
$$
I.e., calculate the determinants of the three $2\times 2$ minors. Rank 2 (some minor $\ne 0$) means that the vectors are l.i.

Comment: But those determinants could be 0, for certain values, no?

Comment: @Nick202, Yes...